# Plot graph for multiple users. Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The sample dataset contains Location point of the user.

```
df.head()

   user           tslot         Location_point
0   0   2015-12-04 13:00:00     4356
1   0   2015-12-04 13:15:00     4356
2   0   2015-12-04 13:30:00     3659
3   0   2015-12-04 13:45:00     4356
4   0   2015-12-04 14:00:00     8563

df.shape 

(576,3)
```

The data contains 2 users each have 288 data points. how to plot 2 users in a single graph.

```
dt =data.iloc[:,2:3]
dt
dt.plot(figsize=(20,10))
```

Tried this where data is datapoints of user 0. How to plot 2 users in a single graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df.set_index('tslot').groupby('user')['Location_point'].plot()`